# Error "DSL compilation failed", "extraneous input ','"

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm having a classic issue in Data Factory where some **forbidden character** causes a failure when parsing the script file and/or the Json code representation.

However in this situation the "extraneous character" (according to the message: an unexpected **comma**) turns out to be elusive. The files I'm looking at don't seem to be the ones that DataFactory is complaining about (there's no **position 47 on line 2**!).

For clarity's sake, I'm only showing **my *one* ultrabasic flowlet.** Could it be that the error is somewhere else in my many flows?  I don't see how, as I click on "Data preview" specifically on *this* flow. Also, it passes validation.

The CSV file:

[image]

[image]

[image]

> Spark job failed: { "text/plain":
> "{"runId":"REDACTED","sessionId":"REDACTED","status":"Failed","payload":{"statusCode":400,"shortMessage":"com.microsoft.dataflow.broker.InvalidOperationException:
> DSL compilation failed: DF-DSL-001 - DSL stream has parsing
> errors\nLine 2 Position 47: extraneous input ',' expecting ...

Showing the files in question :

```
source(useSchema: false,
    allowSchemaDrift: true,
    validateSchema: false,
    ignoreNoFilesFound: false,
    format: 'delimited',
    container: 'newmessagingtemp',
    folderPath: 'testinputs',
    fileName: 'conversation_top_3.csv',
    columnDelimiter: ',',
    escapeChar: '\\',
    quoteChar: '\"',
    columnNamesAsHeader: true) ~> conversationsTop3
conversationsTop3 output() ~> conversationsTop3Output
```

and

```
{
    "name": "conversations_csv",
    "properties": {
        "description": "Use a CSV file in place of the source SQL Table for Conversations ",
        "folder": {
            "name": "Tests (can be deleted)"
        },
        "type": "Flowlet",
        "typeProperties": {
            "sources": [
                {
                    "linkedService": {
                        "referenceName": "AzureBlobStorage1",
                        "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
                    },
                    "name": "conversationsTop3",
                    "description": ""
                }
            ],
            "sinks": [],
            "transformations": [
                {
                    "name": "conversationsTop3Output"
                }
            ],
            "scriptLines": [
                "source(useSchema: false,",
                "     allowSchemaDrift: true,",
                "     validateSchema: false,",
                "     ignoreNoFilesFound: false,",
                "     format: 'delimited',",
                "     container: 'newmessagingtemp',",
                "     folderPath: 'testinputs',",
                "     fileName: 'conversation_top_3.csv',",
                "     columnDelimiter: ',',",
                "     escapeChar: '\\\\',",
                "     quoteChar: '\\\"',",
                "     columnNamesAsHeader: true) ~> conversationsTop3",
                "conversationsTop3 output() ~> conversationsTop3Output"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please note that this issue happens only when I load the CSV in a Flowlet (using a "Source" brick). When I do exactly the same thing in a Data Flow (still using a "Source" brick)  then the error does not happen. I tried deleting and re-creating the flowlet, the issue remained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error "DSL compilation failed", "extraneous input ','"
Error "DSL compilation failed", "extraneous input ','"

> Error "DSL compilation failed", "extraneous input ','"

I tried to reproduce the issue and got similar error.

[image]

**The issue is because we are not using the schema of file.**

To resolve this, you need to import the schema for the file. you can import schema by go to **Projection >> Import Schema >> import**

[image]

***Output:***

[image]

Comment: Never in a million years did I see that blue "import" button at the bottom of the "import schema" panel. I thought that at least one field was mandatory, and that this panel was only meant to redefine some kind of conversion for each primitive type (Date, time, etc.)